# ExtJS GridPanel with a column to upload a file

Tags: extjs6.2

I want to have `Ext.Grid.Panel` with some text columns and one column to upload a file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, before you post question, Please read [about Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`widgetcolumn`**](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html) with [**`filefield`**](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.File.html) widget.

**Code snippet:**

```
{
    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'signature',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'signature'
    }
}
```